# Android back button

Tags: android

In my app I have a button that if the user clicks than a text box appears on the screen
(I use the setVisibility from GONE to VISIBILE).
the problem I have is when the user presses the BACK button on the device : it closes my app.

Is there any way that when the user presses the BACK button than my code will be called (so I can set the visibility to GONE) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works since API level 1:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //Do whatever you want 
        //AND 
        //return true to tell the framework you did handle the back key
        return true;
    }
    //This is not the back key, just ask the framework to behave as usual.
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Starting from API level 5 (android 2.0) you can also use:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Do something (or nothing) here
    return;
}
```

See [this android developer blog message](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html) for a complete overview.

Comment: the default finish will not work when we do no call super class method super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event) as look over my code;

Comment: @ArpitGarg, you mean that returning `false` in the `onKeyDown` above will not `finish()` the Activity?

Comment: yes returning false in the onKeyDown above will not finish() the Activity...tht's why I suggested that

Answer (score 1):

Override [`onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) with your desired functionality.

*The default implementation just calls `finish()` to close the current activity.*

Comment: _Note:_ This is only available with Android 2.0 and higher. (API Level 5)

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            // Put your code here
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Comment: **Caution!** you happen to cancel _every_ keypresses by unconditionally returning true here. This is bad if you try to use an `EditText` :)

Comment: thanks,,, you are right the return true will cancel every key presses